# schedule a method to run between 5AM to 10PM every hour daily

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scheduling

I have program which scrapes table from a site `sitetoscrape.net`, and I have a program which logins to a site `sitetologin.com`. Now I have to put the data scraped to the input box on the logged in site. So I have written a separate program importing the methods from scraper and login program.

Now problem is I want to run the scraper method in between 5AM and 10PM every hour, every day. I could have achieved it using cronjob but the twist here is I have to keep the website logged in throughout the day, whole week, which I achieve by refreshing the `sitetologin.com` every hour, so I can't use cronjob. Is there a way to get this done using python?

I am using selenium to scrape and keep the site logged-in.

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/? I run a couple of daily processes on there (incl Selenium using pyvirtualdisplay).

Comment: the problem is I have to keep it running all the time, with few methods being called at different intervals @blacktj

Comment: They offer "always on tasks" https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks/